# How to list SVN details of all repositories with same name but pon different paths

Tags: linux, unix, svn, tortoisesvn

I have a following tree structutre in SVN for different projects

```
/svn/Project1/Release1/
/svn/Project1/Release2/
/svn/Project1/Release3/
/svn/Project2/Release1/
/svn/Project2/Release2/
```

I want to list out details of all projects having Release 2 folder.

Comment: @akash bhagat - Do you mean list of all content for projects that have `Release1` sub folder under root `/svn`? Is it necessary to list files name, revision number, author, date etc?

Comment: You understood it correctly, but not necessarily all details. Only file name and revision number will suffice

Comment: It is difficult to do this with just `svn` command. But it is possible to write a small C/C++ code that will do this.

Comment: Ok, is there any way to do it in python or java, can't use C/C++

Answer (score 0):

You can process the output tree structure through awk and so:

```
awk -F\/ '$4=="Release2" { print $3 }'
```

Using / as the field delimited, if the 4 delimited field equals Release2, print the 3rd delimited field.

Comment: This one works but imagine a svn structure having almost 50 projects each having 30 Release folders on an average which is ever increasing. This process is extremely slow. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

You can use svn search option (1.14)

`svn list -R --depth infinity <URL/svn> --search "*Release2*"`

if you need details like last commit and so on you can use

`svn list -R --depth infinity <URL/svn> --search "*Release2*" -v`